# DataFrame read from excel (all sheets) not recognizing index and columns

Tags: python, excel, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I wrote the following code ( see 2) below) to extract and manipulate some data from an excel file that looks the following way:

**1) Excel file content, in each sheet:**

```
         Time           F1         F2         F3
41030.00069444  -83.769997      29.430000      29.400000   
41030.00138889  -84.209999      28.940001      28.870001   
41030.00208333  -84.339996      28.280001      28.320000
```

**2) Code:**

```
raw_data = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/linnkloster/Desktop/Results/01_05_2012 Raw Results.xls', skiprows=1, header=0, nrows=1440, dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format='%d/%m/%Y %H')

raw_data[u'Time']= pd.to_datetime(raw_data['Time'], unit='d')

raw_data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_data[u'Time']), inplace=True)

print raw_data

ave_data = raw_data.resample('h', how='mean')
```

**I'm running into two issues:**

**I)** I really need to read in the data from **all the sheets** in my excel file (all of which have the same format as shown above, but different column names). When I add `sheetnames=None` as an input to `pd.read_excel` in the first line of my code to achieve this, it stops recognizing the column titles and index from the Excel file, making it impossible for me to take averages/manipulate the raw_data DataFrame the way I need to (as seen in the last line of code where the new ave_data DataFrame in created). Can anyone help me develop code that will extract the data from ***all the sheets*** in my Excel file, while still recognizing the column headers and the index column so I can manipulate it?

**II)** raw_data currently outputs the following:

raw_data:

```
                        Time           F1            F2            F3
2082-05-03 00:00:59.961599999  -83.769997      29.430000      29.400000   
2082-05-03 00:02:00.009600000  -84.209999      28.940001      28.870001   
2082-05-03 00:02:59.971200000  -84.339996      28.280001      28.320000
```

The date displayed here is slightly wrong - it should be 2012-05-01 - but the hour is correct. Does anyone know how I can change my code to correct this?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: When you set sheetname=None you get a dictionary of dataframes, just making sure you're aware

Comment: I did understand that, but I'm not sure I fully understand what that entails? Can I convert it back to a regular DataFrame, or, alternatively, how can I manipulate this dictionary of DataFrames the way I need to (averaging ect.)? I've tried searching information on dictionaries of DataFrames but unfortunately not found anything particularly helpful.

Comment: It's just a regular dictionary where the key is the  sheet name and the dataframe is the value.  You have to loop through the dictionary and manipulate each sheet individually, there is no way to modify them all at once.

Comment: Ok. Great, that is helpful. Could you help point me in the direction of somewhere I could read more about commands that would help me loop through all my sheets and manipulate the content of each DataFrame? What kind of command lets me access each DataFrame for example? Thank you very much!